# Do including header files make the program heavier in c

Tags: c

Do including header files such as stdio.h, conio.h or any other makes our code or program heavier

Comment: How do you weigh a compute program?

Comment: Since [one GB weighs about 0.5 micrograms](http://superuser.com/a/11503), I wouldn't worry too much...

Comment: It depends upon the implementation (e.g. the compiler) and the optimization flags. BTW `<conio.h>` is *not* a standard header (unavailable on POSIX systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including header files inserts all the content from them into the translation unit on pre-processing.

If the include has only declarations(which is usually the case) and the functions are implemented in library files, the code doesn't get heavier. If the header files include implementation, it will be compiled on compilation, thus making the file heavier.

You can read more about compilation steps here:
http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html

Comment: A header file normally only contains data *declarations*, so including a header does not add "all the data";  the linker does that when the data is explicitly referenced.

Comment: you can deduce that its what i meant when saying if the header include implementation.

Comment: Not really, since that part refers to implementation of functions, not instantiation of data.

Comment: @Clifford I thought it was clear, i edited the answer thank you

Comment: I am not sure it is either clearer or correct.  Did you mean "preprocessing" rather then "pre-compile".  Precompilation is a method employed by *some* compilers to reduce build time - it is proprietary, and not defined by the language.  Suggest: "Including a header file *inserts* all of its *content* into the translation unit during *pre-processing*" - that in itself does not increase code size - that depends on the content.  Your use of the word *data* in the first line is confusing, since you are not referring to instantiated or declared data *objects*.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try including them and building an EXE, then not including them and building an EXE, and see what happens to the file size. I suspect you'll find that the linker is clever enough to only build what's necessary into the EXE.

Answer (score 1):

For typical release builds, **no**.  Header files typically only contain declarations, and unused declarations do not contribute to the size of release builds.  Header files can contain inline function definitions, which might be emitted by your compiler if the definition is not optimized out.  However, this will probably not apply to system headers like `<stdio.h>`.

For typical debug builds, **yes**.  Debugging data often contains information about declarations even if those declarations aren't used in the program.  This way you can use those declarations in the debugger.  Modern debuggers include function definitions, enums, and even preprocessor definitions these days.

That said, you can put *anything* in a header file.

The primary effect of unnecessary header file inclusions is to make the build process take longer.

Answer (score 0):

*Normally* a header file contains declarative statements only.  Declarations in themselves do not add to code size.  Referencing the declared symbols anywhere in the code will cause the linker to include the code *defining* the declared symbols.

Because a header file must be parsed by the compiler in the context of the code in which it is included,  the build time can be extended by header file inclusion.  Very large or deeply nested headers such as windows.h for example can have a considerable effect in this way.

Additionally if you are using an IDE with code navigation and comprehension facilities such as auto-complete and syntax checking, the IDE must parse the code in a similar manner to the compiler, and here again header files can slow that process down.

While you should avoid including unnecessary header files, those containing declarations fuse in teh code are unavoidable - or at least avoiding them will lead likely lead to errors, repetition and make the code hard to maintain.